# Showing a block matrix is SPD

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices

Let $$M := \begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}$$ where both $A$ and $B$ are $N \times N$ symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices. Show that $M$ is also SPD.

$M$ is clearly symmetric. Now to show that the eigenvalues of $M$ are positive, is it enough to observe that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are positive, and so are those of $M$ (as they are the same: [How to find the eigenvalues of a block-diagonal matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307998/eigenvalues-of-a-block-diagonal-matrix))?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid line of reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$
    v=\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1   \\
    v_2   \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are $n\times 1 $ vectors so $v$ is $2n\times 1$ vector. Therefore we have:$$v^TMv=\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1^T  & v_2^T \\
    \end{pmatrix}M\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1   \\
    v_2   \\
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1^T  & v_2^T \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    A & 0   \\
    0 & B   \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1   \\
    v_2   \\
    \end{pmatrix}=v_1^TAv_1+v_2^TBv_2$$
since both $v_1^TAv_1$ and $v_2^TBv_2$ are positive so is $v^TMv$ which implies positive definition of $M$.

Comment: Isn't using the eigenvalues a easier proof though?

Comment: Which proof do you mean? That of mine is using directly the definition of eigenvalues...